# In Rails 3.1, how can I cache the results of a AR query to a cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

For an AR query like this:

```
@users = User.find(some_conditions_here)
```

then @users is an AR array and I want to cache this.

If I do, in one controller call, a

```
Rails.cache.write('foo',@users)
```

it doesn't complain or error out and I can even see a 'foo' under /tmp/cache with a non-zero size but a subsequent controller call to

```
Rails.cache.read('foo')
```

returns a nil. When I do both the write and read from a Rails console, it works as expected. What is it about doing it via a controller that causes this problem?

This used to work before in Rails 2... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `config.action_controller.perform_caching` is set to `true`.

To quote the [Rails caching guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html),

> caching is disabled by default for development and test, and enabled for production

Comment: Checked that already Vivien. For now I have taken to caching the ids of the User model. Would be good to cache the AR objects and never have to hi the DB at all...